# Angularjs compile ng-controller html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I have the below below controller.

```
 myApp.controller('sampleController', ['$scope','$http', $compile',function ($scope, $http, $compile) {

     $scope.name = 'vaibhav';
     var htmlString = '<div ng-controller="sampleController">
                         <p> {{name}} </p>
                       </div>';

     var element = angular.element(htmlstring).scope();
     var compiledom = $compile(element);

     console.log(compiledom); // I need parsed controller view here
 });
```

Final output of  "compiledom" variable should be:

```
<div ng-controller="sampleController">
    <p> vaibhav </p>
</div>
```

I need to use the parsed controller view for creating another dynamic page.

Anything wrong in the above code? Please help me with the right approach.

Comment: Controllers are not intended for DOM manipulation.  You need to do this in a Directive.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Explain higher level use case and problem you are trying to solve. Can't have a controller create itself in the view. Your code will never run and controllers aren't used to manipulate the DOM

Comment: @jbrown If using Directive is a right approach, please tell me how can i do this?

Comment: I do belive, that maybe you want a directive.

Comment: Don't you think a directive would be the best way to achieve 'dynamic pages'?

Comment: @Vaibhav I would start here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive to get an understanding of why, then search for tutorials to figure out how.

Comment: Make that div the template of a directive. `sampleController` would be the directive controller and in this case `{{name}}` would come from scope.

Example: `<a-directive name="vaibhav"><a-directive>`

Comment: @Chanthu Can you make a jsfiddle demo ?

Comment: @charlietfl I have to use the final variable (controller html view) to create another page.

Comment: @VaibhavChiruguri : here you go: https://plnkr.co/edit/ElcJQBEsesi4JwYxRJ9T?p=preview

Comment: no idea what *"create another page"* means. That needs more of an explanation that just 3 words

Comment: Sounds like you need to install a router in your app

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this would be to use a directive.

Make that div the template of a directive. `sampleController` would be the directive controller and in this case `{{name}}` would come from scope.

Example: `<dynamic-page name='vaibhav'></dynamic-page>`

The implementation of directive would look something like this:

```
app.directive('dynamicPage', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      name: '@'
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.number = 10;
    },
    template: '<div><p>{{name}} + {{number}}</p></div>'
  }
});
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ElcJQBEsesi4JwYxRJ9T?p=preview
`

Comment: my template code varies everytime and it is too long. Can i use template url? such as another html page

Comment: You can surely use template url

Comment: I've updated the plunker to show how you can pass in a dynamic page template